# Why does hashCode() function generate an error

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class Measurement {
int count;
    int accumulated;
    public Measurement() {}
    public void record(int v) {
        count++;
        accumulated += v;
    }
    public int average() {
        return accumulated/count;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (this == other)
            return true;
        if (!(other instanceof Measurement))
            return false;
        Measurement o = (Measurement) other;
        if (count != 0 && o.count != 0)
            return average() == o.average();
        return count == o.count;
    }
    public int hashCode() {
        (1) INSERT CODE HERE 
    }
}
```

Which code, when inserted at (1), will provide a correct implementation of the `hashCode()` method in the following program? Select the two correct answers.

`(a) return 31337;`

`(b) return accumulated / count;`

`(c) return (count << 16) ^ accumulated;`

`(d) return ~accumulated;`

`(e) return count == 0 ? 0 : average();`

The correct answer is (a) and (e). (b) is incorrect because of count if it is 0, it will generate an arithmetic Exception, but I don't know the mean of (c) and (d).  Why they are false?

Comment: Those are bitwise operations

Comment: `a` is not a "correct" implementation. It will compile but will give all objects the same hashcode which is exactly the opposite of what you want.

Comment: Did my answer answer your question? If so, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [general contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) of `Object.hashCode`. The question is basically asking you which of those choices fulfils the general contract.

> - Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently
>     return the same integer, provided no information used in equals
>     comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain
>     consistent from one execution of an application to another execution
>     of the same application.
> - If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must
>     produce the same integer result.
> - It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on
>     each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.
>     However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct
>     integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of
>     hash tables.

Your understanding of why B is incorrect is correct. C and D are incorrect because they do not fulfil the second point. That is, they do not work with `equals`.

As you can see, the `equals` method compares the averages if the `count`s are both not 0, otherwise it compares the `count`s.

Option C is taking into account both the count and accumulated, so (accumulated: 6, count: 2) and (accumulated: 3, count: 1) would have unequal hash codes, but would be considered equal by `equals`.

Option D is taking into account only the accumulated, so (accumulated: 6, count: 2) and (accumulated: 3, count: 1) would have unequal hash codes, but would be considered equal by `equals`.

Option A is a weird one. It returns a constant integer. This means that all objects will have the same hash code. Although it is not required by general contract to have a different hash code for different objects (see point 3), it is rarely useful to do this.